# VB.net Intellisense instances vs shared Function

Tags: vb.net, intellisense, shared

Is it possible to disable the list of Shared calls(functions,properties,etc) in intellisence when we are on an instance?

Can this be done using Resharper?  ex.:

```
Dim ex1 = Class1.SomeSharedFunction() ' OK

Dim obj as new Class1()
Dim ex2 = obj.SomeSharedFunction ' I don't want to see this in intellisence list.
```

Why?
Because when you work with some API that are not totally Object Orieted or have a lot of shared functions it becomes a mess.

Comment: VS should be telling you `Access of shared member through an instance...will not be evaluated` in the case of `obj.SomeSharedFunction`  isnt that warning enough?

Comment: Which version of visual studio are you using? The newer version has a more intelligent intellisence. They also show different icon.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.
I know Vs warn me about but i wish it didn't even show in the list.
I'm using VS 2010.